# Accessing array as parameter in $.get from javascript variables in php using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I use the code below to access the id of the login button when clicked. But i want to be able pass the id, user and pass variables into the $.get request and retrieve or access each of them from the php file instead of just one ({menu: this.id}).

My code in javascript:

```
$('#login').on('click', function(){
    let status = true;

    let user = document.getElementById("signinUsername").value;
    let pass = document.getElementById("signinPassword").value;

    //params = [{ menu: this.id }, {username: user}, {password: pass}];
            
    $.get('validate.php', {menu: this.id}, function(data){
         if (data !== "true"){
            status = false;
            alert(data);
         }
    });
    return status;                      
});
```

My code in php:

```
switch($_GET['menu']){

    case 'login':
        $user = validUsername('mary', $conn);
        $pass = validPass('password', $conn);
        if (!$user || !$pass){
            echo "Either Username or Password is incorrect";
        }else{
            echo "true";
        }
            break;
        default:
            someDefaultFunction();
            break;
    }
```

Comment: You can pass the data like this: `{menu: this.id, user: user, password: password}`

Comment: And how will I access it in the php file?

Comment: Note using GET with important credentials is not a good secure idea and you should POST them

Comment: The same way you get the `menu` data: `$_GET['user'], $_GET['password']`